# Issues compiling rosbag_storage on OSX

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, ros

Compiling Ros (Jade) on OSX using [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source), I get the following error for `rosbag_storage` while running `./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`:

> ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rosbag_storage/src/buffer.cpp:71:5: **error**: use of undeclared identifier 'assert'
>       assert(buffer_);

And then a bunch of errors of the kind:

> /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:916:9: **error**: use of undeclared identifier 'assert'
>           BOOST_ASSERT( deleter_.use_count() <= 1 );

Where could that come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was coming from a conflict with GStreamer, like in [this issue](https://github.com/luckybulldozer/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer/issues/15). Just removing `/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers/assert.h` was enough to solve the problem:

```
mv /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers/assert.h /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers/assert.h.bak
```